# ListBox items not showing

Tags: wpf, data-binding

So I've coded a simple data binding practice project, but I have a little problem. I have an ObservableCollection which I data-bound to the ListBox. When I run the program it seems at first that there is nothing in the ListBox, but when I hover my mouse over it I can see the outline of exactly the same number of items as in the ObservableCollections, but nothing says on them.
Here's my code:

XAML:

```
 <ListBox Margin="0, 40, 0, 0" x:Name="lb1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="_age" Text="{Binding Path=Age}"/>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="_cash" Text="{Binding Path=Cash}" />
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="_name" Text="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="_gender" Text="{Binding Path=Gender}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Code-behind:

```
public class Person{
    public Person(string _FullName, int _Age, string _Gender, string _AboutMe, decimal _Cash)
    {
        this.FullName = _FullName;
        this.Age = _Age;
        this.Gender = _Gender;
        this.AboutMe = _AboutMe;
        this.Cash = _Cash;

    }
    public string FullName;
    public int Age;
    public string Gender;
    public string AboutMe;
    public decimal Cash;
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

   public ObservableCollection<Person>People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        People.Add(new Person("John Doe", 35, "M", "My name is John Doe", 1500));
        People.Add(new Person("Sarah Maine", 28, "F", "My name is Sarah Maine", 2150));
        People.Add(new Person("George Smith", 65, "M", "My name is George Smith", 4999));
        People.Add(new Person("Rachel Ramsey", 46, "F", "My name is Rachel Ramsey", 3199));
        People.Add(new Person("Rachel Ramsey", 46, "F", "My name is Rachel Ramsey", 3199));
        InitializeComponent();

        lb1.ItemsSource = People;

    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Need to be public property with a "get"

Answer (score 2):

Your Person-Class needs some Properties and not only fields:

```
public class Person {
    public Person(string _FullName, int _Age, string _Gender, string _AboutMe, decimal _Cash) {
      this.FullName = _FullName;
      this.Age = _Age;
      this.Gender = _Gender;
      this.AboutMe = _AboutMe;
      this.Cash = _Cash;

    }
    private string fullName;
    private int age;
    private string gender;
    private string aboutMe;
    private decimal cash;

    public string FullName {
      get {
        return fullName;
      }

      set {
        this.fullName = value;
      }
    }

    public int Age {
      get {
        return age;
      }

      set {
        this.age = value;
      }
    }

    public string Gender {
      get {
        return gender;
      }

      set {
        this.gender = value;
      }
    }

    public string AboutMe {
      get {
        return aboutMe;
      }

      set {
        this.aboutMe = value;
      }
    }

    public decimal Cash {
      get {
        return cash;
      }

      set {
        this.cash = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

Consider to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` too